# Why the waypoints list and the agents list are empty?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a WaypointsClass class :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using UnityEngine.AI;

[Serializable]
public class WaypointsClass
{
    public List<Transform> points = new List<Transform>();
    public List<NavMeshAgent> agents = new List<NavMeshAgent>();
}
```

Then created WaypointsAI script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaypointsAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public WaypointsClass waypoints;
    public float distanceToContinue;

    private float currentDistanceToPoint;
    private int lastPointIndex;
    private int goalPointIndex;


    void Start()
    {
        //Firstly check if the waypoints are set up correctly
        if (waypoints.points.Count < 1)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Set up the waypoints for this gameObject!");
        }
        else
        {
            //Now set up the path
            lastPointIndex = 0; //Start from the index 0
            waypoints.agents[0].transform.position = waypoints.points[0].position;
            if (waypoints.points.Count > 1)
            {
                goalPointIndex = 1; //Go to the [1] waypoint
            }
            else
            {
                goalPointIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.agents.Count; i++)
        {
            //Calculate the distance and check if it should move to the next waypoint.
            currentDistanceToPoint = Vector3.Distance(waypoints.agents[i].transform.position, waypoints.points[goalPointIndex].position);
            if (currentDistanceToPoint <= distanceToContinue)
            {
                //Save the old index, totally useless in this implementation though
                lastPointIndex = goalPointIndex;
                //Increase goal index to change the goal waypoint to the next, (Or maybe random one?)
                goalPointIndex++;
                if (goalPointIndex >= waypoints.points.Count)
                    goalPointIndex = 0;
            }

            //Now move towards the current waypoint, Change this to fit your code with navMesh anyway I think I did a lot for you anyway
            waypoints.agents[i].transform.LookAt(waypoints.points[goalPointIndex].position);
            waypoints.agents[i].transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Then added for each group of agents and waypoints a script. Red and Blue :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class RedWaypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] redWaypoints;
    public NavMeshAgent redAgent;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        redWaypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Red_Waypoint");

        WaypointsClass wpc = new WaypointsClass();

        foreach (GameObject point in redWaypoints)
        {
            wpc.points.Add(point.transform);
        }

        wpc.agents.Add(redAgent);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

And blue :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class BlueWaypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] blueWaypoints;
    public NavMeshAgent blueAgent;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        blueWaypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blue_Waypoint");

        WaypointsClass wpc = new WaypointsClass();

        foreach (GameObject point in blueWaypoints)
        {
            wpc.points.Add(point.transform);
        }

        wpc.agents.Add(blueAgent);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Then I created in the Hierarchy and in the Scene group of red waypoints and red character and group of blue waypoints with blue character :

[image: Waypoints]

What I want to do the main goal is to move the blue character between the blue waypoints and move the red character between the red waypoints using the same WaypointsAI script. And if the blue group will have 5 character then move the 5 character between the blue waypoints same if the red group will have 50 characters they will move between the red waypoints.

The first problem for now is that the lists points and agents are empty in the WaypointsAI script.
I added a break point to this line :

```
if (waypoints.points.Count < 1)
```

And both lists are empty.

I tried to move the code in the Start() in both scripts RedWaypoints and BlueWaypoints to the Awake() and it does a new instance for the WaypointsClass class but when it's getting to the WaypointsAI scripts the lists are empty. I can't figure out why.

Even simpler in this screenshot I have two characters the one in t pose and the droid with the blue circle in the middle. and I want each one to move between other waypoints. one can move up the stairs and back the other move to the window and back :

[image: Simpler]

Comment: I dont understand, have you one list of points and agents for both red and blue, or each group have its list of points and agents?

Comment: @Frenchy Each group have their own list of points and agent/s. The main goal idea : I want to have multiple characters moving between different waypoints. For example I added 20 cubes tagged them as "Waypoint" and I have 3 characters I want each character to move between different waypoints. For example character 1 will move between cubes 1 to 5 character 2 between 3 and 10 character 3 between 11 and 20

Comment: ok you want WeaponsAI could reach Red and blue agents and points?

Comment: Right.  And each script red or blue can have multiple agents and waypoints. Could be for blue one waypoint with 5 characters that will move between the characters original position and the waypoint and the red will have 10 characters and 30 waypoints and the red characters will move between the 30 red waypoints.

Comment: @Frenchy Even simpler in this screenshot in the link I have two characters the one in t pose and the droid with the blue circle in the middle. and I want each one to move between other waypoints. one can move up the stairs and back the other move to the window and back. imgur.com/a/FAyWVWr

Comment: hum i see you are using Droid and robot, are they free objects 3D?, i am looking after to do a simulation, could you indicate where i could download the both objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem : you cant access to the instance of class created in another script.

If i have understood your problem... I suggest you to use Static Class and Static list so you could access from anyscripts:

```
public static class Waypoints
{
    public static List<Transform> Redpoints = new List<Transform>();
    public static List<NavMeshAgent> Redagents = new List<NavMeshAgent>();
    public static List<Transform> Bluepoints = new List<Transform>();
    public static List<NavMeshAgent> Blueagents = new List<NavMeshAgent>();
}
```

---

```
public class RedWaypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] redWaypoints;
    public NavMeshAgent redAgent;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        redWaypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Red_Waypoint");

        foreach (GameObject point in redWaypoints)
        {
            Waypoints.Redpoints.Add(point.transform);
        }

        Waypoints.Redagents.Add(redAgent);
    }
    :
    :
}
```

---

```
public class BlueWaypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] blueWaypoints;
    public NavMeshAgent blueAgent;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        blueWaypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blue_Waypoint");


        foreach (GameObject point in blueWaypoints)
        {
            Waypoints.Bluepoints.Add(point.transform);
        }

        Waypoints.Blueagents.Add(blueAgent);
    }
    :
    :
}
```

From another Script, if you want to access first Red point item, you just type `Waypoints.Redpoints[0]`  and for your First Red agent you just type `Waypoints.Redagents[0]`  and same thing for blue side

In WaypointsAI you dont need to declare `public WaypointsClass waypoints;`